# Replacing part of delimited string with R's regex

Tags: regex, string, r

I have the following list of strings:

```
name <- c("hsa-miR-555p","hsa-miR-519b-3p","hsa-let-7a")
```

What I want to do is for each of the above strings
replace the text after second delimiter (-) with "zzz".
Yielding:

```
hsa-miR-zzz
hsa-miR-zzz
hsa-let-zzz
```

What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
> gsub("([A-Za-z]+-)([A-Za-z]+-)(.*)", "\\1\\2zzz", name)
[1] "hsa-miR-zzz" "hsa-miR-zzz" "hsa-let-zzz"
```

There are actually several ways to approach this, depending on how "regular" your expressions actually are. For example, do they all start with "hsa-"? What are the options for the "middle" group? Might there be more than three dashes?

Answer (score 3):

Might as well use something like:

```
gsub("^((?:[^-]*-){2}).*", "\\1zzz", name)
```

`(?:[^-]*-)` is a non-capturing group which consists of several non-dash characters followed by a single dash character and the `{2}` just after means this group occurs twice only. Then, match everything else for the replacement. Note I used an anchor just in case to avoid unintended substitutions.